# Get the resulting number with js

Tags: javascript

So basically my problem is that am trying to figure out how to calculate and return a number with JS according to the following logic.

Ex: i have a number of 120 i want to check well is the number greater than 100 ( yes ) okay is the number less than 200 ( yes ) then return ( 1 * 300 )

Ex : another number as 230 is the number greater than 200 ( yes ) okay is the number less than 300 ( yes ) then return ( 2 * 300 )

and sooo on.

i made it through switch case but it think it is too odd to do this and it is possible to deal with large numbers like 10000 , 20000 so i will need endless switch cases or if conditions

i hope you got my point

Comment: Where does the 2 come from in 2*300?

Comment: something like `Math.floor(n/100)*300`? Not considering negative numbers and other edge cases, that is?

Comment: if the actual number is greater than 200 and less than 300 , then i need resulting  number to be 2 * 300 and so one , if the actual number is greater than 300 and less than 400 i need resulting number to be 3 * 300 etc ... for endless

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+number+ranges+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: @PinguinDirk definitely it is the direct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comment above, not considering edge cases (negative numbers for example), you might go with:

```js
Math.floor(n / 100) * 300
```